# Cómo hacer consulta usando WITH sobre tabla temporal?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sintaxis

Alguien me podría ayudar con el error de esta consulta, utilizando tablas temporales con WITH.

El  error que me aparece es el siguiente:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ')'.

```
WITH table_2 AS
(select*
from cm_ocomp)
```

La consulta la hace un par de días y funcionaba, realizo esta consulta en SQL y en Postgres y pasa los mismo.

Comment: Es una `temporary table` que definiste o con "Tabla temporal" te refieres a lo que armas en el WITH? Son cosas diferentes. Ahora bien, la consulta que pones está incompleta, pues no sabemos si el error se debe a que usas mal table_2 o alguna otra cosa. Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir la consulta completa?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia está incompleta.

Si bien la parte del *CTE* está bien formada, luego no haces nada con este CTE, es decir, no hay una consulta principal:

Si lo cambias por esto:

```
WITH table_2 AS
(select *
from cm_ocomp)
select * from table_2;
```

Dejará de aparecer el error (puesto que ya hay una consulta).

Obviamente, hacer todo esto, sin ninguna transformación, no tendría sentido, pues la consulta podría reducirse simplemente a:

```
select * 
  from cm_ocomp
```

Que entregaría los mismos resultados.

Comment: Perfecto funciono a la perfeccióon muchas gracias